# Sever-less AWS Lambda Dynamodb throw internal error

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, lambda, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

I made one todo app by using lambda. I used sever-less framework for deployment. I made one post request where user can create a todo-list. For testing I am using post-man. For my Lambda function I am using async function. I can able to make post request and my item store in Dynamo db but I got response `Internal server error`. My goal is show in my postman what I kind of post request I made.

Here is my code:

```
'use strict'
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.createTodo = async (event) => {
  const datetime = new Date().toISOString();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: 'todos',
    Item: {
      id: uuid.v1(),
      task: data.task,
      done: false,
      createdAt: datetime,
      updatedAt: datetime
    }
  };
  try {
    let data = await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
    return JSON.stringify(data); // this throw me internal server error.
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling the Lambda function via API Gateway, you need to convert the response to the following structure -

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  // headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, // Uncomment if needed by your client
}
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I changed the payload and did not deploy it that's why I got the error. But I used your return but now I got empty object. is there any way I can retrieve the post payload,

Comment: You are returning `data` which is the ddb putItem response. Do you want to return that or the function input? Can you add console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) before you return and check what is getting logged?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Lambda. I got what you mean now, I added event body now I am getting: `"{\n    \"task\": \"nodddnhjbhfyuyttdrdtrsrtydryrddytucddddddfyufyfiyifuyii\"\n}"`. is there any way I can just display : "task": "nodddnhjbhfyuyttdrdtrsrtydryrddytucddddddfyufyfiyifuyii"

Comment: I did this:   let response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: event.body,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, // Uncomment if needed by your client
    }
    return response;

I got what I wanted but my question is how I just got the body